# Zend Framework Adding Search Option

Tags: zend-framework, search

I am new to the Zend Framwork. I would like to add search function on the existing module. When the user enters the name in the textbox it should return the corresponding record. Could someone help me to add this function?

Thanks

PS: I don't want to use lucene

Comment: i know you said you don't want but , you should consider lucene, it is fairly easy to use and would be a better and fast way to implement search..

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
define thes variable in your model
```

and add this function

```
 protected $_name = 'your_table_name';// table name


 public function getAll($order = null, $count = null, $offset = null) {

        $rows = $this->fetchAll(NULL, $order, $count, $offset);

        return $rows->toArray();
    }
```